# How to pass a piece of code as argument to a function in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here in the below code i am using toast message called [react-native-toast-message](https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message/blob/945189fec9746b79d8b5b450e298ef391f8022fb/docs/custom-layouts.md) installed via npm to show some custom messages. So in the below function when ever toast message is hide automatically , it has a feature to execute a function within onHide in below showToast function.  since i want to execute different code , i am passing code as a argument to function ,but code get never executed.

if i add a code within  onHide , it does execute code  , it does works as shown in below code ,but it does not fullfill my need. Any help would be highly appreciated to help how to pass this piece of code via argument to onHide

> onHide:()=>{props.onPickScreen('Bar')},

```
 function showToast(value1,value2,value3,value4){
        Toast.show({
          text1:value1,
          text2:value2,
          position:'top',
          type:value3,
          onHide:()=>{value4},   // code passed via value4 get never executed on hiding toast message 
         
        })
      }


 showToast("Reservation process failed "," please rescan it  ","error","props.onPickScreen('Bar')");
```

> // if i pass code without parenthesis then it does execute code before
> showing even toast message

```
 showToast("Reservation process failed "," please rescan it  ","error",props.onPickScreen('Bar'));
```

Comment: You're passing in a string. Instead, you can pass in the actual function as `value4` and then set "onHide" to that.

Comment: @Pointy if i execute code as you described without parenthesis , code get executed before even showing toast messagebox. actually it was suppose to execute when text message is hide . most probably issue with this npm packages

Comment: You're passing `props.onPickScreen('Bar')` which means to **call** the function and pass the result. You need to pass an anonymous function like in your original code, `() => props.onPickScreen('Bar')` as the fourth parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute code when the onHide callback is triggered, you need to pass a function reference as the value for onHide. It seems like you're trying to pass code as a string, which won't be executed in this context.

Here's how you can modify your showToast function to correctly handle the onHide callback:

```
function showToast(value1, value2, value3, onHideCallback) {
    Toast.show({
        text1: value1,
        text2: value2,
        position: 'top',
        type: value3,
        onHide: onHideCallback
    });
}
```

And when you call the showToast function:

```
showToast(
    "Reservation process failed ",
    "please rescan it  ",
    "error",
    () => props.onPickScreen('Bar')
);
```

By passing the function reference directly instead of a string, the code inside the onHideCallback function will be executed when the toast is hidden.

Comment: if i execute code as you described without parenthesis , code get executed before even showing toast messagebox. actually it was suppose to execute when text message is hide . most probably issue with this npm packages

Comment: @James you're putting `( )` where they shouldn't be.